# disable versions on Mavericks

Tags: macos, iwork, versions

I have been using this command to get back Save As... in Mountain Lion and it works great:

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no
```

However, this doesn't seem to work anymore in Mavericks. Ut seems that it's just the older iWork '09 apps that can't use the Save As function.

All the other apps (textedit, preview, etc) are able to use Save As. So are the newer iWork apps (the ones just released). But I use the older iWork 09 apps the most. Is there anything I can do to bring the functionality back on those?

Answer (score -1):

you might can use this hint: http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/27/enable-save-as-os-x-mountain-lion/ It worked for me.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone